# Mac `option` key works as `meta` key in terminal Emacs but does not work in GUI Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I checked the <kbd>option</kbd> key as <kbd>meta</kbd> in terminal preference. Now the <kbd>option</kbd> key works as <kbd>meta</kbd> in terminal.

Once I open Emacs through terminal <kbd>option</kbd> key doesn't work as <kbd>meta</kbd> anymore. If i type <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> The result comes out as a check mark.

I've added the next line to my init file but still doesn't work.

```lisp
(setq ns-option-modifier 'meta)
```

Now I can only use <kbd>ESC</kbd> as meta.

Any idea why the keybinding doesn't change in Emacs?

Comment: try `M-x` customize-group `RET` ns `RET`, do not forget to apply customization.

Comment: Thanks. In my custimize-group when I type ns, nsm group comes out instead. Any idea why? I am using macport-emacs. I uninstalled my spacemacs now the meta key is set to command for some reason. @Muihlinn

Comment: Sadly no, I gave up with OSX long ago, but looks like you don't have that group. 

Back then I used to use the X11 Emacs, and IIRC there were options to avoid keys interferring between the system and X11 apps. To make things even difficult there it was system Emacs (very outdated, IIRC without X) and whatever you installed. You need someone with an up-to-date OSX knowledge to dig this further. 

My main point was that a `defcustom` may not be properly set up with `setq` in your init file, thus ignored.

Comment: macports Emacs can be compiled/installed with variants, yous should check if yours was configured with `--with-ns` (nextstep-cocoa windows system) evaluating `(featurep 'ns)`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following config

```
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta))
```

Comment: Note that the test is not necessary, because the variable has simply no effect on other systems.